# can't start rails server, getting a lot of "load errors"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-1.8.7

I am trying  to setup an existing project of friends on my ubuntu 
i installed ruby ree-1.8.7 with rvm
and ran the `rvm use` command to switch to that ruby.
then ran bundle install in the app folder and it installed all the gems (there are a lot)

now i tried running `rails server` and i am getting a huge amount of errors.
i won't copy all the text because its big, but here is how it looks basicly. how do i go about solving this?

```
/home/schaller/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- twitter-text (LoadError)
from /home/schaller/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /home/schaller/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /home/schaller/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/schaller/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /home/schaller/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /home/schaller/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/twitter-2.0.0/lib/twitter/status.rb:9
from /home/schaller/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /home/schaller/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /home/schaller/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /home/schaller/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/schaller/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /home/schaller/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /home/schaller/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/twitter-2.0.0/lib/twitter/user.rb:5
from /home/schaller/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not a huge amount of errors, its just one error and what you are seeing is the stack trace :)

The real error is:

```
`require': no such file to load -- twitter-text (LoadError)
```

So add twitter-text to your Gemfile and try again ;)